# A trapezium encloses half circle bisecting its diagonals. Find angle of the trapezium.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

Let $ABCD$ be a trapezium with parallel sides $AB$ and $CD$ such that the circle $S$ with $AB$ as its diameter touches $CD$. Further, the circle $S$ passes through the midpoints of the diagonals $AC$ and $BD$ of the trapezium. The smallest angle of the trapezium is ______.

Can anyone please tell me how to proceed?
I think some more information needed to solve the problem.

Comment: All the information is there. Only one trapezium is possible for the circle. Try sketching it. The line CD touches the circle at one point (you can call this point E). So *the line CD must be a long one* if the mid-points of the diagonals are to be points on the circle S.

Comment: The midpoints of the diagonals are on a line that is parallel to and equidistant from the lines AB and CD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The triangles AFO and ACB are similar since AO = OB, AF = FC and shared angle $\alpha$, , which leads to BC = 2OF = 2r. From the right triangle BEC, we have $\sin\angle$BCE = BE/BC = $\frac12$. Thus, the angle is 30$^\circ$.

[image]

Comment: That's a nice proof

Comment: A lot more economical than my procedure (or the other answer, I think).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I have to write 30 characters to sumbit an answer...

Comment: If you cut off the part of the picture below the figure and typed the text below it, you'd have more than 30 characters already.

Comment: It's quicker for me to write than type. Is my writing OK or is it illegible?

Answer (score 0):

Technically only a semicircle is inscribed in the trapezium. The other half of the circle is outside.

Let the diagonal $AC$ intersect the circle at $E.$
Construct a line through $E$ perpendicular to $AB$ and $CD,$ intersecting $AB$ at $F$ and $CD$ at $G,$ as in the figure below.

[image]

Let $O$ be the center of the circle and $H$ the point of tangency with $CD.$
Identify two congruent triangles in this figure (the figure is not to scale), thereby showing that
$EF = EG = \frac12FG.$ Also show that $FG=OH=OE.$

Now examine the right triangle $\triangle OFE.$ You have two of the sides; find the remaining angles.

This gives you the central angle $\angle BOE.$ Now you can find the inscribed angle $\angle BAE.$
This is equal to $\angle ACD.$
Moreover, $\triangle ABE$ is a right triangle (since $AB$ is a diameter and $E$ is on the circle), and therefore so is $\triangle BCE,$ and since $AE=CE$
this leads to $\angle BCE=\angle BAE.$
Now we have two angles whose sum is $\angle BCD.$

Comment: Do you just use paint for the diagram?

Comment: @AdamRubinson Yes. I saw no need for anything more powerful. I almost decided not to draw the figure at all.